# Provide dependency with Dagger2

Tags: android, google-maps, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm using a [library](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions) (examples fake to simplify the question, but the essence remains unchanged) that wraps the Google map, like to decorator for GoogleMap and has MarkerManager for add, remove markers etc.

**//Library**

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

public class DelegatingGoogleMap {

    GoogleMap map;
    MarkerManager manager;  

    public class DelegatingGoogleMap(GoogleMap map){
        this.map = map;
        this.manager = new MarkerManager(map);      
    }
}


import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

public class MarkerManager {

    public class GoogleMap map;

    public class MarkerManager(GoogleMap map) {
        this.map = map;
    }       
}
```

In app I want use own `MarkerManager's`

**//App**

```
public class MarkerManagerExtended extends MarkerManager {

    public class MarkerManager(GoogleMap map) {
        super(map);
    }

}
```

So I want use Dagger 2 to inject MarkerManagerExtended to DelegatingGoogleMap (property injection).

```
public class DelegatingGoogleMap {

    GoogleMap map;

    @Inject
    MarkerManager manager;  

    public class DelegatingGoogleMap(GoogleMap map){
        this.map = map;
    }
}
```

Not sure, Dagger used in this case is a good idea.

The problem is that in `Module` to provides an instance of a `MarkerManagerExtended` I have to pass com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap to the constructor.

```
   @Module
   public class MapModule {
        @Provides
        public MarkerManager providesMarkerManager() {
              return new MarkerManagerExtended(map); //map instance of com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
        }
    }
```

Getting GoogleMaps does not look easy, so I'm not sure I should write this in `Module`.

```
    public class MapFragment extends com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment {

        GoogleMap map;

        public void getMapAsync(final OnMapReadyCallback callback) {
            if (map != null) {
                callback.onMapReady(map);
            } else {
                getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap realMap) {
                        map = realMap;
                        callback.onMapReady(map);
                    }
                });
            }
        }   
    }

    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

Any ideas how to MarkerManager inject into DelegatingGoogleMap?

Comment: How did you solve this problem? Can you explain if you solved?